# Using 'this' in an object in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using Electron to create a little desktop app and exporting with `module.exports`. On the 'server' side this works fine. However, when I'm using module.exports on the front end, as per Electron docs, I get this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: this.showProgressbar is not a function"`

```
var ViewController = {
    getPageCount: function (res) {
        this.total = res;
        this.showProgressbar(res);
    },

    showProgressBar: function (num) {
        $('.progress-container').addClass('show');
        $('.progress-bar').style('width', '0%');
    }
};

module.exports = ViewController;
```

On the client side, this is how I'm accessing this file.

```
var view = require(__dirname + '/client/ViewController.js');

ipc.on('page_count', view.getPageCount);
```

How should I be accessing internal methods in this instance?

Comment: this.showProgressBar is looking for showProgressbar on getPageCount not in the ViewController object.

Comment: What if you use this? `ipc.on('page_count', view.getPageCount.bind(view))`

Comment: You need to call your function with the correct case too: `this.showProgressBar(res);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewController is neither a 'Class' nor an instance, its a plain javascript object with two properties.

If you want it to behave like a class and be able to acccess to other properties from a method when creating an instance this is how you should do:

```
var ViewController = function(ipc){
        this.ipc=ipc;
        this.ipc.on('page_count', this.getPageCount);
};

ViewController.prototype.getPageCount: function (res) {
        this.total = res;
        this.showProgressbar(res);
},

ViewController.prototype.showProgressBar: function (num) {
    $('.progress-container').addClass('show');
    $('.progress-bar').style('width', '0%');
}
module.exports = ViewController;
```

You still need to instantiante ViewController :

```
var ViewController = require(__dirname + '/client/ViewController.js');

var controller = new ViewController(ipc);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because when the callback is being called, it's being called in the wrong context. To bind the context, use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
ipc.on('page_count', view.getPageCount.bind(view));
```